# Mi proyecto de laravel no carga estilos

Tags: css, laravel, style

Mis estilos que estoy cargando:

```
<!-- Styles -->

<!-- Estilo de la aplicaicon : app.css-->
<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Estilos propios: style.css-->
<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

El estilo `app.css` es el de la propia app.
Debajo estoy cargando unos estilos propios que se llaman `style.css`.

Esta dentro de la carpeta `resrouces/css` del proyecto
y no hay manera de que coja los estilos

Comment: Por que estás confundiendo donde se deben almacenar tus hojas de estilos y los js, dichos archivos [van en la carpeta public](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory) como indica la propia documentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace "*asset*" es ir a la carpeta public y buscar los archivos de ahí.

Mueve tu archivo de la carpeta `resources/css` a `public/css`.